# Cant move an html image and I dont know why

Tags: html, css

This is my code. I have done the CSS and the HTML code so that this logo image that I have moves to the right.

However, the image remains still. What am I doing wrong?

HTML CODE:

```css
#logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 200 px;
  border: 25px black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="LogoSIEM.PNG" alt="logo" style="width:200px;height:200px">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what exactly did you mean by move the image to the right? right all the way to the right corner or just move it to right by 200px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `right: 200 px;` to `right: 200px;`

The space before `px` is invalid, so it doesn't recognize it as being 200px from the right.

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
body {
 position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float:right instead of what you have tried to do in your css....

```css
#logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 25px black;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="LogoSIEM.PNG" alt="logo" style="width:200px;height:200px">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```